# Function to create a table with min and max of each date in the dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe, max, min

I am new to R and I am trying to create a function that would create a new dataframe showing min and max of each Date´s column from the original dataframe.
I have a dataframe (df) with different types of variables (numeric, dates, character...).I would like to create a function that will select only Date columns (Date1,Date2,Date3,Date4, number of columns can vary...).and creates a new dataframe showing me min and max of each of Date´s columns (see the output below).

**Input dataframe df** (number of date column can vary):

```
Num1     |     Chr1  |     Date1    |    Date2     |  Date3       |
```

---

```
1        |     Name1 |   2012-01-01 |   2018-02-01 |  2015-05-01  |

2        |     Name2 |   2013-01-01 |   2016-02-01 |   2014-05-01 |

3        |     Name3 |   2014-01-01 |   2014-02-01 |   2013-05-01 |
```

**Output dataframe** df1:

```
      |  min_Date1    |  max_Date1   | min_Date2   | max_Date2 |  min_Date3 |  max_Date3 |
      -------------- --------------  ---------- ------------- ------------ -------------
date  |  2012-01-01   |  2014-01-01  | 2014-02-01  | 2018-02-01| 2013-05-01 | 2015-05-01 |
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by the `dplyr` package or by regular expression. We first create the sample data frame:

```
# The data frame
data <- data.frame(
  Num1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  Char1 = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3"),
  Date1 = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2014-01-01")),
  Date2 = as.Date(c("2018-02-01", "2016-02-01", "2014-02-01")),
  Date3 = as.Date(c("2015-05-01", "2014-05-01", "2013-05-01"))
)
```

**By `dplyr` package**

```
df_max <- dplyr::select(data, dplyr::starts_with("Date")) %>% 
  lapply(max) %>% 
    as.data.frame

df_min <- dplyr::select(data, dplyr::starts_with("Date")) %>% 
  lapply(min) %>% 
    as.data.frame
```

**By regular expression**

```
df_max <- as.data.frame(lapply(data[grep("^Date", names(data))], max))
df_min <- as.data.frame(lapply(data[grep("^Date", names(data))], min))
```

**Combining the two data frames**

```
names(df_max) <- paste0("max_", names(df_max))
names(df_min) <- paste0("min_", names(df_min))
df1 <- cbind(df_min, df_max)
df1 <- df1[, c(rbind(names(df_min), names(df_max)))]
```